# Merge two JSONs from groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have 2 JSON files and I want to merge those 2 and create one JSON message using groovy. Based on the "type" value I'm going to merge those two JSON files.

- If the given "type" of JSON objects of JSON message 1 does not exist
  in the JSON message2, the relevant JSON object should be contained in the output JSON message.
- All the JSON objects from JSON message2 should be contained in the
  output JSON message
- Expected sample formats is shown below

Input JSON message1

```
{"message":[{"name":"HelloFile","type": "input"},{"name":"SecondFile","type": "error"}]
```

Input JSON message2

```
[{"name":"NewFile","type": "input"},{"name":"MyFile","type": "output"}]
```

Expected JSON

```
{"message":[{"name":"NewFile","type": "input"},{"name":"MyFile","type": "output"},{"name":"SecondFile","type": "error"}]}
```

I used the below groovy code.

```
JsonBuilder jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(JSON1)
jsonBuilder.content.message= JSON2
def updatedBody = jsonBuilder.toString()
```

From the above code, I got the below message.

```
{"message":[{"name":"NewFile","type": "input"},{"name":"MyFile","type": "output"}]}
```

Any help sorting this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JsonSlurper:

```
import groovy.json.*

​def json1 = '{"message":[{"name":"HelloFile","type": "input"},{"name":"SecondFile","type": "error"}]}'​​​​​​​​​​​​​
def json2 = '[{"name":"NewFile","type": "input"},{"name":"MyFile","type": "output"}]'
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json1Obj = slurper.parseText(json1)
def json2Obj = slurper.parseText(json2)
json1Obj.message+=json2Obj
println JsonOutput.toJson​(json1Obj)​
```

This prints:

```
{"message":[{"name":"HelloFile","type":"input"},{"name":"SecondFile","type":"error"},{"name":"NewFile","type":"input"},{"name":"MyFile","type":"output"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the expected result is different from above. If the given "type" of JSON objects of JSON message 1 does not exist in the JSON message2, the relevant JSON object should be contained in the output JSON message. So, in the output message, there shouldn't be duplicate types.

Comment: Well in this case you'll have to write some code for the merging logic. I've shown the way to process json objects in groovy way... for example instead of += you could iterate over messages and check....

Comment: @KittyKotte It's something like `([[a:1],[a:2]] + [[a:1],[a:3]]).collectEntries{ [it.a, it] }.values()` from here